# Animation in eBook for Kindle using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, kindle

I want to create a Kindle eBook with using HTML and CSS. I am able to create a basic eBook with some HTML pages using "calibre". 
But the project requirement is to use the animations inside the HTML pages...like if we click on a balloon it just blows. I have tried using animation is CSS but it didn't work.

Please help me with some links or sample code.

Comment: I doubt that many e-books support interactions like you describe (like clicking on stuff and animating it). A Kindle e-ink screen updates very slowly so even if it did the result would probably not be nice to look at. On the other hand, if you are targetting the Kindle Fire it has a web browser that you may be able to use.

Comment: I dont want to have a WebApp...I just want a eBook that can be ported to Kindle devices. I am creating the .ePub file and then further converting it to .Mobi file. and if this is slow(though my Html pages are very light)...will try to manage that. Can you refer me a link about the animations?

Comment: I don't know what to link to except this question. I'm just expressing that I doubt you will be able to do animations in any e-book format supported by the Kindle. Just because you can use HTML as a source file for an e-book doesn't mean that whatever you can do using HTML in a browser can be done in an e-book.

Answer (score 1):

The Kindle devices as e-book readers do not support animations whether they be CSS or jQuery or pure JavaScript or anything else.